# How do I make emitter particles come to one point?

Tags: particles

So yeah I just want it to look like this(a particle system with gravity off in reverse). Is there something really simple I'm forgetting?

Like this -------> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7Y8KLwU8CY

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide some context and explanation by verbally describing your issue, don't just post, images, videos, files to download, or links to external sites. See [What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “*How do I do this?*”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Make a normal particle system, but render it in reverse?